# Множественая отправка формы

Tags: jquery, php

Всем добрый день подскажите пожалуйста в чем может быть причина множественой отправки письма через форму. Форма отправляется следующим образом.

```
$("#myForm").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {

            $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                });

            var m_data=$('#myForm').serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ajax/feedback.php',
            data: m_data,
            success: function(result){
                $('#form_div2').slideUp(1000);
            $('#res').html(result);
            }
            });

        },
       rules:{
            email:{
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                maxlength: 30,
                email: true,
            },
            phone:{
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 16,
                digits:true,
            },
            privod: {
                required: true
            },
            marka: {
                required: true
            },
            model: {
                required: true
            },
            god: {
                required: true
            },
            dvig: {
                required: true
            },
            det1: {
                required: true
            },
            doptext:{
                minlength: 6,
                maxlength: 500,

            },
       },

       messages:{

            email:{
                required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
                minlength: "В имени должено быть минимум 2 символа",
                maxlength: "Максимальное число символо - 16",
                email: "Введите правильный E-mail",
            },
            phone:{
                minlength: "Телефон должен быть минимум 6 символа",
                maxlength: "Телефон должен быть максимум 16 символов",
                digits: "В поле должны быть только цифры",
            },
            privod:{
                required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
            },
            marka:{
                required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
            },
            model:{
                required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
            },
            god:{
                required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
            },
            dvig:{
                required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
            },
            det1:{
                required: "Это поле обязательно для заполнения",
            },
            doptext:{
                minlength: "Текст сообщения должен быть минимум 6 символов",
                maxlength: "Текст сообщения должен быть максимум 500 символов",
            },
       }

    });

});
```

Код обработчика следующий:

```
        echo "Ваш запрос успешно отправлен!";

$subject = "Сообщение с сайта ".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."";

$message = '
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Новое сообщение с сайта</title>
    </head>
    <body>';
$message .= '

Марка: '.iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST["marka"]).'
<br/>
<br/>
Модель: '.iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST["model"]).'
<br/>
<br/>
Год выпуска автомобиля: '.iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST["god"]).'
<br/>
<br/>
Объем двигателя: '.iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST["dvig"]).'
<br/>
<br/>
Привод: '.iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST["privod"]).'
<br/>
<br/>
Телефон: '.iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST["phone"]).'
<br/>
<br/>
E-mail: '.iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST["email"]).'
<br/>
<br/>
Деталь 1: '.iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST["det1"]).'
<br/>
<br/>
Деталь 2: '.iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST["det2"]).'
<br/>
<br/>
Деталь 3: '.iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST["det3"]).'
<br/>
<br/>
Деталь 4: '.iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST["det4"]).'
<br/>
<br/>
Деталь 5: '.iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST["det5"]).'
<br/>
<br/>
Дополнительная информация: '.iconv("utf-8","windows-1251",$_POST["doptext"]).'
';

$message .= '
    </body>
</html>';

$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251 \r\n";
$headers .= "From: Feedback <".$_POST['email'].">\r\n";

mail('емаил для отправки', $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Но каждое письмо приходит до 7 - 8 экземпляров никаких циклов нигде нет незнаю даже в чем может быть проблема ХЕЛП !!

Comment: видно на этом сайте у вас эти 7-8 раз инициализировался код валидатора. Т.е. смотрите на страницу может несколько раз подключен тот же самый js. Я такое видел на нескольких сайтах

Comment: Помоиму всетаки не в этом дело посмотрел код страницы все подключено по одному разу

Comment: В общем у вас проблема именно в js. 
Я вижу следующее:
вы нажали отослать данные - потом зачем-то переопределяется событие submit для #myForm зачем???
Опять нажали отослать уже дважды переопределили событие вот вам уже 4
Еще раз нажали вот вам 8 писем.

Попробуйте выести этот код из обрботчика:
         $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                });

Comment: Такой код использую не на одном сайте и все работает замечательно без кучи отправок (( попробую последовать совету но если будут еще варианты напишите.